# Airflow not connecting to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have a docker-compose where the airflow is runnig on my pc(windows) and i'm trying to insert some data into MySQL that is also running on my computer but not on a container, and i keep runing into the same error:

```
[2022-03-29, 20:27:01 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1264} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): collecting_data> on 2022-03-29 20:27:01.023525+00:00
[2022-03-29, 20:27:01 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 20187 to run task
[2022-03-29, 20:27:02 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'bloomberg_commodity', 'collecting_data', 'manual__2022-03-29T20:27:01.023525+00:00', '--job-id', '45', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/bloomberg_commodity.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpwv6m8kg8', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpatl2gni8']
[2022-03-29, 20:27:02 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 45: Subtask collecting_data
[2022-03-29, 20:27:02 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: bloomberg_commodity.collecting_data manual__2022-03-29T20:27:01.023525+00:00 [running]> on host 822a66e6d6f5
[2022-03-29, 20:27:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1431} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=bloomberg_commodity
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=collecting_data
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-03-29T20:27:01.023525+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-03-29T20:27:01.023525+00:00
[2022-03-29, 20:27:02 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1718} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 236, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)
```

the airflow can access the internet and i know this because i do it in the DAG:

```
    action_get = 'https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/948434/historical/chart/?period=MAX&interval=P1M&pointscount=120'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36'}

    res = r.get(action_get, headers=headers)

    valores = res.json()["data"]

    valores_list = []
    for vl in valores:
        valores_list.append(tuple(vl))
    
    #insert my sql
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='suzano_stage',
                                         user='suzano',
                                         password='suzano123')

    mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO suzano_stage.bloomberg (date, close, open, high, low, volume, avg_volume) 
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, valores_list)
    connection.commit()
    
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

in case someone asks this is the .yaml file for the docker compose

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.4}
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

I searched a lot online and couldn't find anyone with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your Airflow is running in a docker container. To connect to your local MySQL, if your docker is running on Windows or Mac replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal`